# Explain "if you want to fight me so bad, bring it on!"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I found this item in Oxford dict. What does the phase "so bad" mean in the example sentence?

> [ bring it ( on ) ] informal used to express confidence in meeting a challenge: if you want to fight me **so bad**, bring it on!

Comment: "so bad" = "that much". *"If you want to fight me so bad ..."* means *"If you want to fight me that much ..."*. Another way to put it is *"If you **really really** want to fight me, ..."*.

Comment: Using *so bad* instead of *so badly*, is also informal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, verbs expressing pain or a negative emotion can take the word "badly" (in very formal English) or "bad" (in spoken English although a prescriptivist will say this is "incorrect.")  This means "a lot." (EDIT: I can only speak for the US when I speak of formal/informal, apparently the version with 'badly' is more widely heard in the UK -- see the comments))

For instance,

My arm hurts ---> My arm hurts bad! (or my arm hurts real bad!)

"I missed you so bad." --Carly Rae Jepsen

By extension, a lot of verbs of "volition" like need/want/hope can take the word "badly" in formal English, or much more commonly "bad" in informal English. It just means "a lot" although it implies that you are suffering a little from how much you need/want/hope for something.

"You want to fight me so bad" -- to me sounds like "you want to fight me so much, you are just going crazy not being able to do it."

Comment: The examples you gave sound typically American. The word *badly* is not "very formal English" as you put it, everywhere in the English speaking world. It's more common here in England and the rest of the UK, than "bad", in that context.

Comment: ah, ok! sorry, i should have qualified that I am American. in America I wouldn't use "badly" unless I was wearing a suit and tie.

Comment: Carly Rae Jepsen is Canadian, so I take that as a data point for that country's English as well!

Comment: huter, you could edit your answer to reflect that American use. I think that English as spoken in Canada is very similar to American English.

Comment: I'm from the US and I wouldn't say that *badly* is formal by any stretch of the imagination. Using *bad* instead of *badly* is a very common error. Perhaps it's going to become so common that it's accepted as correct; I'm not sure. But that certainly doesn't make *badly* formal!

Comment: I personally find badly quite pretentious and would not recommend an english language learner use it in America. Perhaps the op can take that as two different data points.